# Case folding conflict in hg after converting from svn

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-convert

I'm thinking about switching to hg from svn so I ran the convert script to convert our 5-year-old svn repository. The conversion ran overnight and didn't appear to have any problems. Then I went to the new hg repo directory and tried to run "hg update" to get a working copy. It immediately fails with the following message:

> abort: case-folding collision between
>   MacApps/BaseCamp/English.lproj/Help/topics/getting_started/getting_started.html
>   and
>   MacApps/BaseCamp/English.lproj/Help/topics/getting_started/Getting_Started.html

How do I fix this problem so that I can get a working copy and start using hg?

Answer (score 0):

Amateur glance makes it seem like the issue is that HG has two files in the repository one with Getting_started.html and the other with getting_started.html (capital G diff). Try the guidance on this page - http://kdbdallas.com/2008/12/23/fix-mercurial-case-folding-collisions/

Comment: That solution doesn't help me because my working copy is empty due to the case-folding error.